# Reset/Set state on a button onClick

Tags: reactjs, react-component

I have a custom form with at least two different types of Components: One for a textfield, and another for a number, and when I click the "Submit" button (itself just a button, not wrapped in a form) I want to set the state of the fields back to 0/Empty. I'm not really clear here on how to restore these to their defaults. I know that I need to pass `setState()` at some point since I can't "zero out" like with traditional Javascript, but I am confused since the click operation would never reference the components. What am I missing here?

```
import './App.css';
import React from 'react';

class NumberField extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { value: 0 };
  }

  changeHandler = event => {
    event.persist();

    let value = event.target.value;

    this.setState(prevState => ({
      item: { ...prevState.value, [event.target.value]: value }
    }))
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <label for={this.props.label}>{this.props.labelName}</label>
        <button onClick={this.decrement}>-</button>
        <input type="number" 
          name={this.props.label} 
          id={this.props.label} 
          value={this.state.value}
          onChange={this.changeHandler}>
        </input>
        <button onClick={this.increment}>+</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class TextField extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { value: "" };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <label for={this.props.label}>{this.props.labelName}</label>
        <input type="text" name={this.props.label} id={this.props.label} placeholder={this.props.placeholder}></input>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function handleSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log("Form Submitted");
  // TODO Reset the state on all components so everything goes back to 0/Empty somehow
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="AppForm">
        <TextField labelName="Ferry Name" label="ferry_name" placeholder="Enter the ferry name" />

        <div>
          <NumberField labelName="Number of seats" label="seats" />
        </div>
      <div className="formSubmit">
        <button onClick={handleSubmit}>Book Ferry</button>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2):

**Note: If you want to access `component's state` inside a function, then you `must` declare that function inside the component.**

---

Other than that,
what you want to do can't be directly achievable by how you are handling `child component's state`.

If you want to change the child component's state, the due to `unidirectional nature` of react, you can't simply access the child's state.

1. What you can do is, you can have a `state = {number:0, text: ""}` in `App Component` and pass `update Functions` and `field values` as `props` to the `Child Components`
2. Another way (**not recommended in react doc**), if don't want to keep your state in Parent is, using `useImperativeHandle`. You can read about it in [Link to doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useimperativehandle)
3. One more way (**recommended for larger projects**), is to use `global state` managements like `redux`, `context`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned you should send two more props, I named them `reset` and `changed`
and also I changed your `class components` to `functional`

```js
const {useEffect,useState} = React;

const NumberField = (props) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (props.reset) setValue(0);
  }, [props.reset]);

  const increment = () => {
    setValue((value) => value + 1);
  };
  const decrement = () => {
    setValue((value) => value - 1);
  };

  const changeHandler = (event) => {
    event.persist();
    props.changed();
    setValue(event.target.value);
    //let value = event.target.value;

    //setValue(prevState => ({
    //  item: { ...prevState.value, [event.target.value]: value //}
    //}))
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <label for={props.label}>{props.labelName}</label>
      <button onClick={decrement}>-</button>
      <input
        type="number"
        name={props.label}
        id={props.label}
        value={value}
        onChange={changeHandler}
      ></input>
      <button onClick={increment}>+</button>
    </div>
  );
};


const TextField = (props) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  useEffect(() => {
    if (props.reset) setValue("");
  }, [props.reset]);
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setValue(event.target.value);
    props.changed();
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <label for={props.label}>{props.labelName}</label>
      <input
        value={value}
        onChange={handleChange}
        type="text"
        name={props.label}
        id={props.label}
        placeholder={props.placeholder}
      ></input>
    </div>
  );
};

const App=()=> {
const [reset, setReset] = useState();
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("Form Submitted");
    setReset(true);
    // TODO Reset the state on all components so everything goes back to 0/Empty somehow
  };
  const handleChanged = () => {
    setReset(false);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="AppForm">
        <TextField
          reset={reset}
          changed={handleChanged}
          labelName="Ferry Name"
          label="ferry_name"
          placeholder="Enter the ferry name"
        />

        <div>
          <NumberField
            reset={reset}
            changed={handleChanged}
            labelName="Number of seats"
            label="seats"
          />
        </div>
        <div className="formSubmit">
          <button onClick={handleSubmit}>Book Ferry</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
ReactDOM.render( <App/> ,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: When using your changes to TextField outside of the snippet, when a change is made on TextField components, it returns an error that `props.changed();` is not a function. Is this because react-dom is necessary here?

Comment: I should see your codes.